# How to install .apk file using adb on nixos?

Tags: android, mobile, adb, nixos

I'm running nixos and I have a .apk file, i.e. an Android app.

There is the handy tool adb (Android Debug Bridge) and the command

```
adb install /path/to/app.apk
```

How do I get it to work on nixos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary `adb` is in `androidsdk`. So either run

```
nix-env -i androidsdk
```

or add `androidsdk` to the list `environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

Your Android phone needs to be plugged in and have USB debugging enabled as documented on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html).

Simply running `adb install ...` didn't work for me. Instead I did

```
sudo adb start-server
adb install /path/to/app.apk
```

or

```
adb install /path/to/app.apk -r
```

for overwriting an already installed app.